# amazon product api returning HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I've access data using the amazon product API before and that was easy. All I had to do was make some api keys and use a module in Python and it gave back the data.
however, this was 4-5 months ago and now when I try to use the api keys, its giving me 400 error.

Here is my code

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

asin = 'B00CAB5ZKC'
AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY='AKIAI4ZP7EZGNSTAWKTA'
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY ='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'
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG =246152698300 
amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG, region = "DE")
product = amazon.lookup(ItemId=asin, Condition='All', MerchantId='All')
```

This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hari\Documents\Python\data\amazon_test_script.py", line 22, in <module>
    product = amazon.lookup(ItemId=asin, Condition='All', MerchantId='All')
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\amazon\api.py", line 173, in lookup
    response = self.api.ItemLookup(ResponseGroup=ResponseGroup, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", line 265, in __call__
    {'api_url': api_url, 'cache_url': cache_url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", line 226, in _call_api
    return urllib2.urlopen(api_request, timeout=self.Timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
  HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
    >>>
```

I've been debugging this for 2 days now, with no success. Could anyone tell me what am I missing.

Comment: What is your `amazon` module? Judging from your stack trace, it seems to be a private module built on top of `bottlenose`.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-simple-product-api/

this is the one i am using. it used to work some time ago. i also tried direct api call but doesnt work either

Comment: Is it possible your credentials have been revoked because of lack of use? Have you tried dropping the `Condition` and `MerchantId` arguments to see if maybe Amazon has changed its API?

Comment: well i have a set of keys that are working with the same set of arguments. Were you able to try these keys at your end and did u get the same error?

Comment: I didn't try, but what is for sure is that you should immediately invalidate those keys and get new ones.

Comment: i have tried that too but the same error persists.

Comment: What Alberto means is that the "secret key" must be kept... well, secret. Whoever knows the key can access the services as if they were you, and you just posted it on a public website...